# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'document')

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to open a new window from a new window and I get the error above.

Here's my SystemModal.js

```
const SystemModal = (props) => {
    console.log(props)
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

    return (
        <Row>
            <Col>
                    <Display tryData = {props.data} type = "systeminformation" />

                    <RepairWindowRegister repairData = {RegisterJson} 
                    type="repairdetails" 
                    buttonName = "Add Repair Item" 
                    textName = "Add Item" 
                    className = "AddItem" 
                    failureInfo = {props.failureInfo} />

                    <FailureWindow className = 'ongoing' 
                    headerName = "Failure Information" 
                    data = {props.failuredata} 
                    failureinformationlength = {props.failureinformationlength} 
                    failuredetailslength = {props.failuredetailslength}  
                    systemdata = {props.data} />


            </Col>
            <br/>
        </Row>
    )
}

export default SystemModal;
```

This component is already rendered inside a new window it looks like this : [System-Modal-Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqc2z.png)

as you can see on the image, RepairWindowRegister and FailureWindow Component correspond to the Add Repair Item button and Open Failure Details button, respectively(these 2 buttons should open a new window). Now when I clicked on either of that buttons it returns this error -

[Repair-Window-Register-Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2qfl.png) in this case I've clicked the Add Repair Item button, same error for the Open Failure Details button.

Here's my RepairWindowRegister.js:

```
function RepairWindowRegister(props) {
    console.log(props)
    const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
    const [open, setOpen] = useState();

    const RenderInWindow = (windowProps) => {

      const [container, setContainer] = useState(null);
      const newWindow = useRef(window);

      useEffect(() => {
        const div = document.createElement("div");

        setContainer(div);
      }, []);
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if (container) {
          newWindow.current = window.open(
            "",
            "",
            "titlebar=yes,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,width=600,height=430,left=200,top=200"
          );

            newWindow.current.document.title = "Register Repair Progress";

          newWindow.current.document.body.appendChild(container);
          const curWindow = newWindow.current;
          copyStyles(document, newWindow.current.document);
          return () => curWindow.close();


          
        }
      }, [container]);
    
      return container && createPortal(windowProps.children, container);
    };


  return (
    <>  
        <Row>
            <Col>
               <span>{props.textName}</span>
             </Col>
        <Col>
        {(open == true)?
        <Button onClick={() => setOpen(false)} 
        className = "input"> {props.buttonName} </Button>
        :
        <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)} 
        className = "input"> {props.buttonName} </Button>
        }
            
            {open == true ?
            <RenderInWindow>
                <RegRepair repairData={props.repairData} 
                failureInfo={props.failureInfo} 
                type="repairdetails"/>
            </RenderInWindow>
            :
            null
            }
        </Col>
        </Row>
    </>
  );
}


export default RepairWindowRegister;
```

Is there a work-around for the error here? Is it really possible to render a new window from a new window?

Comment: You're trying to access `newWindow.current.document` but `newWindow.current` is `null`. You can't read property `document` of `null`. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: @jabaa why it is returning null even I have a declaration of the newWindow?

Comment: [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open): _"Return value ... If the window couldn't be opened, the returned value is instead null."_

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to render a new window from a new window but...

`newWindow.current` is null since the method `window.open()` is not actually opening anything when the code is executed, but why ? Add Blockers.

[Opera Add blocker on codesandbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXjnT.png)

Your code does work as long as the current browser is not blocking adds(like yours and mine and probably everyone elses).

A workaround ? trigger and open the modal yourself with a handle method and not at the self component mounting cycle.